# Print the value in Hash of Hash for two different keys in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

Below is a hash in Perl:

```
my %hash = (
            'episode1' => {
                            'when' => '08.13.97',
                            'airdate' => '08.13.97',
                            'episodenumber' => '101',
                            'id' => '103511',
                            'title' => 'Cartman Gets an Anal Probe',
                            'available' => 'true'
                          },
            'episode2' => {
                            'when' => '08.20.97',
                            'airdate' => '08.20.97',
                            'episodenumber' => '102',
                            'id' => '1035156',
                            'title' => 'Weight Gain 4000',
                            'available' => 'true'
                          }
);
```

I want to print the "id" of both episodes,but the below code is not working:

```
foreach my $key1 ( keys %hash ) {
  foreach my $key2 ( keys %{$hash{$key1}} ) {
    print "$hash{$key1}{$key2}{id}\n";
  }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach my $key1 ( keys %hash ) {
    print "$hash{$key1}{id}\n";
}
```

or

```
foreach my $key1 ( keys %hash ) {
  foreach my $key2 ( keys %{$hash{$key1}} ) {
    print "$hash{$key1}{$key2}\n" if($key2 eq 'id');
  }
}
```

Comment: It wasn't my vote, but I'd guess it was because you give code to solve the problem, but no explanation of what was wrong with the original code or why the new code works.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is a first when perfectly fine code is being down voted. Apparently every place has its share of idiots.

Comment: @Andrey It's not nice to call people who disagree with you "idiots". I can see why a downvote could have come about if the user thinks the answer wasn't useful. The disagreement is about what's "useful": Working code is useful, and so is an explanation. The fact that one user values explanations does not make said user an idiot.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Platinum Azure.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: I am not here to be nice or rude. I am here to help people when I can and ask for help if needed. A solution that solves a problem is useful by definition. I would really like to know how many useless answers are accepted as correct solution.

Comment: @Andrey Well, as the saying goes, "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime." Your code is useful for a day, but it's better to teach someone why the code works as it does so that the knowledge can be transferred to other problems. I didn't downvote you and the OP accepted your answer, so there's really no point in quibbling-- it's just a difference in philosophy. My answer is also mostly code-driven, so I'm not criticizing you. I only responded in the first place because you called the downvoter an idiot, and I thought was uncalled for.

Comment: @Andrey It's not my vote either, but in most answers I would expect to see not just the solution, but a brief explanation of why the original code didn't work... could you add it?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're trying to print something that doesn't exist: There is no value that matches `$hash{$key1}{$key2}{id}`.

Try this code, which prints out the value in the hash of hashes that has the key "id":

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $episode (keys %hash){
    print "$hash{$episode}{id}\n";  
}
```

---

```
103511
1035156
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `map`:

```
my @ids = map { $hash{$_}{"id"} } sort keys %hash;
```

Or if you still need the results as a hash:

```
my %ids_by_key = map { ($_, $hash{$_}{"id"}) } keys %hash;
```

Comment: Worth noting, this answer is the way to go if you're trying to store the IDs for later iteration/use. If you don't need to have those data in a data structure and just need to iterate for printing, the other two answers are simpler.